# Why isnt the position tweening?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am fairly new to Lua, and I am trying to make a game in Roblox. I am currently working on an open and close button on my Miner GUI.

## Code

```
local Frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.MinerGuiManager.MinerFrame
local Opened = false
if Opened == false then
    print('Gui Is Closed')
    Opened = true
end
if Opened == true then 
    print('Gui Is Opened')
end
script.Parent.Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    GUI:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0),'Bounce',1.5)
    
    
end)
```

I want the GUI to disappear and reappear

[Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHphJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GUIObject:TweenPosition](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/function/GuiObject/TweenPosition) function has a few parameters. Some have defaults, but if you want to override them, you need to override them in the right order. Your example looks like it is missing the *easingDirection* argument.

Also, you need to call TweenPosition on the object you want to animate. In your example, it will be the variable Frame.

```
-- define some variables and grab some UI elements relative to the script's location
local Button = script.Parent.Button
local Frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.MinerGuiManager.MinerFrame
local Opened = false

Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    local TargetPos
    if Opened then
        -- move the frame offscreen to the lower right
        -- NOTE - once we move it offscreen, we won't be able to click the button
        --        and bring it back onscreen... (change this number later)
        TargetPos = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
    else
        -- move the frame to the center of the screen
        local frameWidthOffset = Frame.Size.X.Offset * -0.5
        local frameHeightOffset = Frame.Size.Y.Offset * -0.5
        TargetPos = UDim2.new(0.5, frameWidthOffset, 0.5, frameHeightOffset)
    end

    -- animate the frame to the target position over 1.5 seconds
    local EaseDir = Enum.EasingDirection.Out
    local EaseStyle = Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce
    Frame:TweenPosition(TargetPos, EaseDir, EaseStyle, 1.5)

    -- toggle the Opened value
    Opened = not Opened
end)
```

Comment: I will try it! Thank you fore all your support

Comment: Thanks this helped me too!